sftp connection using the following command: sftp user@host, fails with message: subsystem request failed on channel 0 Connection closed
I'm trying an sftp connection using the following command: sftp user@host, but fails with message: subsystem request failed on channel 0 Connection closed. On the contrary when running: ssh user@host to the same host this connection is successful.
I'm attaching the full sshd-config file I use:
    #       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.104 2021/07/02 05:11:21 dtucker Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# To modify the system-wide sshd configuration, create a  *.conf  file under
#  /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/  which will be automatically included below
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-dss
Ciphers +aes128-cbc

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
MaxSessions 50

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in RHEL and may cause several
# problems.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
MaxStartups 300
Match User amssftp
ChrootDirectory /ams
ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002

Can you please help me to overcome this issue?
I'm attaching the command output with -vv option:
 [root@localhost ~]#  sftp -vv admin@10.85.220.158
    OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
    debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 10.85.220.158 originally 10.85.220.158
    debug2: match not found
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
    debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
    debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.85.220.158 is address
    debug1: re-parsing configuration
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
    debug2: checking match for 'final all' host 10.85.220.158 originally 10.85.220.158
    debug2: match found
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
    debug1: Connecting to 10.85.220.158 [10.85.220.158] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_3.5p1
    debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_3.5p1 pat OpenSSH_3.* compat 0x01000002
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to 10.85.220.158:22 as 'admin'
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
    debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc
    debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
    debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: compression ctos: none
    debug2: compression stoc: none
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
    debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 need=20 dh_need=20
    debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 need=20 dh_need=20
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:ZlIlk1cHA8WnjeJxK+DrLleDOiTlfb1cOMypierJ1Ww
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: Host '10.85.220.158' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:5
    debug2: bits set: 500/1024
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    admin@10.85.220.158's password:
    debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
    Authenticated to 10.85.220.158 ([10.85.220.158]:22) using "password".
    debug1: pkcs11_del_provider: called, provider_id = (null)
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug2: channel 0: send open
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: pledge: filesystem full
    debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
    debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
    debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
    debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
    debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
    debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
    debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
    debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 100 id 0
    subsystem request failed on channel 0
    Connection closed
    Connection closed.


Try to change the subsystem to Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

I've already tried this and didn't work.

Try to remove also Match user from the config. And do not forget to restart ssh daemon

also this modification din't work. I got the same response :-(

The sshd configuration file that you posted has this:
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Your debug output includes this line:
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_3.5p1

This says the remote server is running OpenSSH version 3.5. This is pretty old. According to the OpenSSH release notes, the "internal-sftp" option for the SFTP subsystem was added around version 4.7.
It seems the SSH server software on the remote system probably doesn't support the "internal-sftp" subsystem feature. You should locate the "sftp-server" program on the remote system, then edit this Subsystem line to list the absolute path to sftp-server:
Subsystem sftp /some/path/to/sftp-server

Alternately, look into updating the remote system to use a more modern version of OpenSSH.
